TradingView: understanding account balance
I have created a paper trading account at TradingView with $100,000 initial balance. After filling a position for some Tesla shares, the account balance still shows as $100,000:

Why isn't the money spent to buy the shares subtracted?

The value of the shares is part of your holdings, and thus part of your balance. If you want your cash balance, that should be available somewhere else in your statement.

@keshlam The balance reflecting the value of my shares is reflected in Equity. The value of the shares at the time when they were purchased is irrelevant, isn't it?

I believe they are showing the purchase value followed by the gain/loss since then, rather than showing current value.
